# Templatized callbacks

Tags: c++, templates

The tagline is probably not very descriptive, but I couldn't come up with a better one. However, I hope to be able to explain the question.

I have a framework, which can be loosely mapped to the following demo code:

```
struct OpaqueStruct {
// OpaqueStruct allows introspection of it's members
// using templatized inrospect()
class OpaqueStruct {
  int i;
  double d;
  void* p;
public:
  template <class T> void introspect(T visitor) {
    visitor(i);
    visitor(d);
    visitor(p);
  }
};

template <class T> struct FunkyCaller {
  FunkyCaller(T* obj, int arg1, int arg2);
  template <class A> void operator() (A a) {
    obj->funky_impl(a, arg1, arg2);
  }
private:
  T* obj;
  int arg1;
  int arg2;
};

template <class T> struct FunkyCaller2 {
  // similar to FunkyCaller, but calls 
  // this->funky2_impl(arg);
};

// Benemoth is full of logic, code, data and lines
class Benemoth {
  OpaqueStruct opaque_data;
  void funky(int arg1, double arg2) {
    // Need to do something funky, taking args and opaque struct
    // as input
    opaque_data.introspect(FunkyCaller<Benemoth>(this, arg1, arg2));
  }

  void funky2(const char* arg) {
    // Need to do something funky, taking args and opaque struct
    // as input
    // opaque_data.introspect(FunkyCaller2<Benemoth>(this, arg));
  }
public:
  template <class ARG>
  void funky_impl(ARG a, int arg1, int arg2);

};
```

There is a lot of code, but I hope the idea is visible - there are different functions in Benemoth, which need to handle opaque_data differently. The setup I have right now, and which I've shown here, works. However, I do not like it, because every time I need to implement a new function to do something new with `OpaqueData`, I need to create a 'caller' class for it. This makes code maintenance hard, as the code is polluted with those 'callers'. Anybody reverse engineering it will have to navigate from `funky()` to `FunkyCaller()` to `funky_impl()`. Not nice.

What I have already considered?

- C++ 14 template lambdas. Would work fine, and my `funky()` would look like `opaque_data.introspect([this, arg1, arg2](auto datum) { this->funky_impl(datum, arg1, arg2); });`. Unfortunately, our project is not ready to use C++14 yet
- C++11 lambdas, various `std::bind`s. Couldn't make it work, since they all require the argument type to be specified - lambdas by the way of requiring you to specify the argument type, binds by the way of wanting a pointer to member
- Macros. Doesn't seem possible, and even if it is, would likely be less readable than the code I currently have

Does anybody see any possible way of decreasing code clutter here? I do not, but probably I do miss something?

Comment: I played with the code for a bit, I think your best bet is to go with macros.
Or wait for C++14